# Keyboard shortcut in Word to close footnotes and return to the main document?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> all the time to add a footnote. Is there any quick way to jump back without using the mouse? It seriously distrupts my flow.

Answer (score 4):

By default, there is no keyboard shortcut for this action, but you can assign one that will close the footnotes pane and take you wherever you were last in the main window.

Go to Customize Keyboard Shortcuts>References Tab>View Footnotes and assign whatever shortcut you like.

Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> drops the footnote, I like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to take me back to where I was when dropped it.

Comment: Great idea! I like Ctrl + Alt + G personally to go back. Would love to see more upvotes on this answer.

Comment: @AaronCampbell Haha. Since writing this, I've actually switched to Ctl+Alt+G myself.

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a keyboard shortcut for that.

What you *can* do is use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> keyboard shortcut which cycles through your last edits. After entering the footnote or endnote text, just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and most of the time, it will take you directly to the insertion point, *if the last point you had been editing was around the footnote marker*.

Answer (score 0):

Though it won't return you to the footnote insertion, you might have some success with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, which will take you to the beginning or end, respectively, of your non-footnote text.